# BigQuery: "Invalid function name"

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I ran this query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(start_time), resource
FROM [logs.requestlogs_20140305]
```

and received the error

> **Error:** Invalid function name: SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP

SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP is listed in the [date functions reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions), so why does this error come up?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my `start_time` column was of type float, not an integer which `SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` expects. Changing the query to

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(start_time)), resource
FROM [logs.requestlogs_20140305]
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. In fact, it's a very confusing error message.